# Lotus Notes configuration

Tags: lotus-notes

I am new to lotus notes and facing one issue. For scrolling in any of the sections of the Notes window(ex: section that shows Inbox,drafts folders;section that shows mails in my inbox; section that shows preview of the currently opened mail) I have to click that particular section. Can I configure it like outlook so that I can scroll just by hovering over the section?

Comment: Pawan, people here are a little bit rude with new users. I'm sorry for them about it. Stackoverflow is a website for QA (question&answer) about programming, and programming only.
You'll want to ask this question in any Lotus Notes specific forum or some FAQ they might have, or also try to ask on superuser.com.Good luck, buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

The focus is something that gets "lost" quite often in the Lotus Notes client. 
Then you have to click in the correct "pane" to get it back

(by the way: this is something that happens to me in Outlook as well, e.g. when I write my responses within the same window... Then I have to click into the mail to get focus back and only then can click again to send the email)

Comment: yeah but once you are inside the outlook window, you can just hover to shift focus to different sub windows